# программа для коррекции сканированных страниц

Tags: изображения, обработка-изображений

у меня есть отсканированные страницы книги, и некоторые получились под углом и с обложкой. какой прогой можно выровнять страницы и по возможности обрезать по границе?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не по теме. Здесь задают вопросы по программированию.

Answer (score 0):

Abby fine reader, adobe acrobat.